# Different database configurations depending on environment when executing integration tests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

I'd like to switch my test database configuration when I execute my integration tests. For the moment, I use a profile 'it' to use a database in development mode. I would like to use another profile when I execute my integration tests on Jenkins CI for example 'jenkins-it'. I don't want to use a memory database (I use Postgresql).
My tests on Jenkins are launched by Gradle using the following command : gradlew test

Here is how I annotate my integration test class :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ActiveProfiles("it")
public MyClassIT {
    @Test
    ...
}
```

It works in development because it uses my 'application-it.yaml' with my defined development datasource. Here is the content of 'application-it.yaml' :

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mfttest?currentSchema=audit"
    username: "testuser"
    password: "testuser"
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
  liquibase:
    enabled: false
```

On Jenkins CI, how can I switch to use my 'application-jenkins-it.yaml' with Jenkins datasource ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the common approach here is to use a application-local.yaml which contains your "development" environment configuration besides the normal application.yaml (or with some other profile). While in "development" mode you run your app or tests with the local profile.

You don't commit application-local.yaml file to the source control (gitignore if you are using git). This way, you can have 2 separate configurations. This is how we do it and I think it is done like this pretty much everywhere.

In addition, you can use [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) to be able to run your integration tests everywhere without worrying about the databases and all other dependencies.